# I don't understand how cin.ignore() works. When I run this piece of code, my program breaks down

Tags: c++, string, oop, cin

There is an array of classes. I want to input an amount of players and then by using a `for`-loop, input player's names. The problem is that I don't understand how to avoid the program crashing, using `cin.ignore()`.

```
void main() {
    int numberOfPlayers;
    cout << "Input amount of players:";
    getline(cin, numberOfPlayers);
    Player** arrOfPlayers = new Player*[numberOfPlayers];
    string newName;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        cout << "\nInput player " << i + 1 << " nickname: ";
        getline(cin, newName);
        arrOfPlayers[i]->setName(newName);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear why you would want to use `ignore` in the above code at all. It looks to me like the problem is trying to use `getline`, which reads a stream into a `std::string`, to read a stream into an `int`. Read into a `std::string` and then use `std::stoi` to convert the string into an `int` you can use to size `arrOfPlayers`.

Comment: Also the elements of `arrOfPlayers`  are never initialized, so `arrOfPlayers[i]->setName(newName);` causes undefined behaviour. It's unclear where and why you want to use`ignore` here. Right now the code won't compile.

Comment: Have you considered using (and are you allowed to use) `std::vector`? It's the natural data type for a job like this. Basically `new` is for chumps who want to do extra debugging or experts solving a special problem.

Comment: Please provide the true code. If I'm not mistaken, there is no simple way to complete it so that it compiles (to have `getline(cin, numberOfPlayers)` with `numberOfPlayers` an `int` to compile for instance needs a quite strange declarations beforehand)

Comment: Do you really need an array of pointers to strings?  I don't think it adds any value like it would if they were C-style strings.  Maybe try something like https://onlinegdb.com/tJAuugBGe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not allocated the individual players

This

```
Player** arrOfPlayers = new Player*[numberOfPlayers];
```

only allocates an array of *pointers* to players

You also need to create those players

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; ++i)
   arrOfPlayers[i] = new Player;
```